# Why doesn't Ubuntu installed on ext4 with "LUBI" work?

Tags: installation

I found this Lubi installer (Linux Ubuntu Installer) which is similar to Wubi, except it allows to install any of Ubuntu derivatives and do it from Linux and not Windows. It is exactly what I needed, installing Ubuntu without having to burn to USB stick, mess again with the partitions, I have the iso downloaded already, it would be just install and run, really useful.

I've tried already to proceed as described [here](http://lubi.sourceforge.net/lubi.html), however, even though all process was easy to follow and appeared to have been successfully executed, when I reboot PC, there isn't Ubuntu option to boot from in the Grub Menu.

Then I checked the requirements and it states that Lubi will not work on any systems using LVM, EVMS, or another logical volume manager, or filesystems other than ext2, ext3, reiserfs, vfat, ntfs, jfs, or xfs.

My home partition default filesystem is ext4, which is not listed in here. This may possibly be the reason why it doesn't work. Is there anyway to make Lubi work on ext4 filesystem? I've been on [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=441918&highlight=lubi%20ext4) already and some other people have this issue as well, but there is no activity in there for over an year and no further updates about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, LUBI does not appear to have been updated [since the days of **Ubuntu 7.04**](http://lubi.sourceforge.net/lubi.html).

While there is no technical reason ext4 wouldn't work with Lubi's methodology (loop-mounted filesystem), gettIng Lubi to do that would require updating it or would require editing of config-files on both the "host/guest" of a Lubi install.

Assuming Lubi even supports the current GRUB2 in the first place, your best option may be to use gparted and carve out a separate ext3 partition just for Lubi filesystems.

Comment: Hmm, indeed it can be an issue with GRUB2 as well, because Ubuntu won't show on boot menu, and as you say, Lubi hasn't been updated for a while, so I will try to create the separate ext3 partition, it would be great if it worked, if not, I believe this is a project with much potential and someone should grab it, try to improve and update it if possible.

Comment: @user64720: I agree...